# u and v are real and imaginary. f(z) is a piecewise function. Show that Cauchy Riemann holds but is not differentiable at 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Say u and v are real and imaginary components.  If given f(z) how would I show that Cauchy Riemann holds at z=0 but is not differentiable?
Let f(z)=$(u-iv)^2$/z when z$\neq$0 and f(z)=0 when z=0

What I have done here so far is assess f(z) by expanding out the conjugate of z and squaring it but I don't think I got any farther than that as the answer I got, which is really long seems to be going nowhere.  Can someone help?

Comment: Not sure what your first sentence means, but if it means $z=u+iv$, that is going to be **really** confusing.  Try changing it to $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=(x-iy)^2/z$.

Comment: u and v are real and imaginary components of z.  I wanted to write in place of the numerator of f(z) z bar.  That's what the actual problem was.

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations involve $\partial u/\partial x$ etc.  If you change $x$ to $u$ and $u$ to something else it is going to be way too confusing for me.  But if you can cope with it, no problem!